# Jquery - Datatables - Capture Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a question. About Javascript.

I'm trying to capture the click in a table.

I did so:

```
"fnDrawCallback" : function() {
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
var id_val = $('td', this).eq(0).text();
alert(id_val);
} ); }
```

This works well.
But my problem is: In my last column, I have a checkbox, when i click, another event occurs, how do I to add a NOT condition?
I tried this:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', ':not(.checkbox)', function () {
```

But it did not work.

For the checkbox i have this:

```
$('#example tbody td').on('click',':checkbox',function() {
alert('Message');
});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: So your problem is: try to seperate two different click event. Is that correct?

Comment: @Alan
Exactly when clicking on the first columns 1 event in last column(Checkbox) another.

Comment: You can try give those different `id`/`class` then referencing them by `id`/`class`, that way there won't be conflict.

Comment: @Alan
I tried but could not. For the first 3 columns class: readonly, to the last: class: checkbox. But I could not find what class is.

Comment: can you post your HTML markup? Or try to use jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Alan http://jsfiddle.net/finando/aZfrg/2/

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/aZfrg/3/
basically I'm just referencing specific `td`s by class

Comment: @Alan Wowwww... Perfect. And simple .. I need to learn more about this.. I lost a few hour, hahaha... Thanks man.

Comment: I just put my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('td.readonly').on('click', function () {
    alert('NOT CHECKBOX');
});

$('td.checkbox').unbind('click').on('click', function () {
    alert('CHECKBOX');
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aZfrg/3/)